# error when try to parse JSON with GSON to spinner android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I got some error when I parse JSON with library GSON to my spinner android. the error is  :

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

when i click at log cat android studio :

error to the line of code `spinnerData = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, Set_jadwal[].class));`

THIS IS full my source code :

```
public class jadwal_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String DATA_URL_KELAS = "http://smpn8pky.rf.gd/Json_kelas.php";
public static final String DATA_URL_JADWAL = "http://smpn8pky.rf.gd/Json_jadwal.php";
public List<Set_jadwal> spinnerData;
private RequestQueue queue;
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jadwal);

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestJsonObject();
}

private void requestJsonObject() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, DATA_URL_KELAS, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson mGson = builder.create();
            spinnerData = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, Set_jadwal[].class));
            //display first question to the user
            if(null != spinnerData){
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiner_kelas);
                assert spinner != null;
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(jadwal_Activity.this, spinnerData);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

and this is the link to my json response [JSON RESPON](http://smpn8pky.rf.gd/Json_kelas.php)

Comment: What does `response` contain? I suspect you are getting some text which is not json.

Comment: wht do you mean, I'm a little less understanding. i wanna parse that json to my spinner .what must i do what my code ???

Comment: Read my answer. It's not a problem with your code but with your webhost.

Comment: oh sorry , i understand now. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to `GET` the JSON from your URL using Postman (Google Chrome plugin), the response tells me this:

[image: Error]

This means that unless the site disables it's requirement to not allow any incoming requests which don't have javascript you will not be able to fetch the json data. The reason websites usually do this is to prevent being spammed by bots.

So to clarify: this is NOT a problem with your code, but rather with (your/the) webhost.

Comment: hmmm.. i think you a right. so what must i do ? is there any setting to fix that on the hosting ?? i use free hosting from https://infinityfree.net/

Comment: There most likely is not a setting that lets you change this. It's a preventive measure that has been put on there by the administrators of the free hosting company. I recommend finding your own (preferably paid, but can be cheap) hosting.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you try to convert JSON array to array of `Set_jadwal` and after to list by using `Arrays.asList`. I think its redundant.

Use `Gson` `TypeToken` to convert directly to List

```
String response = "[{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-1\",\"kelas\":\"VII-1\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-2\",\"kelas\":\"VII-2\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-3\",\"kelas\":\"VII-3\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-4\",\"kelas\":\"VII-4\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-5\",\"kelas\":\"VII-5\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-6\",\"kelas\":\"VII-6\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-7\",\"kelas\":\"VII-7\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-8\",\"kelas\":\"VII-8\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-9\",\"kelas\":\"VII-9\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-10\",\"kelas\":\"VII-10\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-11\",\"kelas\":\"VII-11\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-12\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-1\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-13\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-2\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-14\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-3\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-15\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-4\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-16\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-5\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-17\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-6\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-18\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-7\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-19\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-8\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-20\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-9\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-21\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-10\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-22\",\"kelas\":\"VIII-11\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-23\",\"kelas\":\"IX-1\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-24\",\"kelas\":\"IX-2\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-25\",\"kelas\":\"IX-3\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-26\",\"kelas\":\"IX-4\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-27\",\"kelas\":\"IX-5\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-28\",\"kelas\":\"IX-6\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-29\",\"kelas\":\"IX-7\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-30\",\"kelas\":\"IX-8\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-31\",\"kelas\":\"IX-9\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-32\",\"kelas\":\"IX-10\"},{\"kd_kelas\":\"KLS-33\",\"kelas\":\"IX-11\"}]";

List<Set_jadwal> result = new Gson().fromJson(response, 
                new TypeToken<List<Set_jadwal>>() {}.getType());
```

where `Set_jadwal` is:

```
public class Set_jadwal {
    private String kd_kelas;
    private String kelas;
}
```

---

As a side note, its not good practice to use `Set_jadwal` as class name ;)